Camera pose estimation using opencv's solvePnP
I have a grayscale camera for which I have already calculated intrinsic parameters with standard methods of calibrations. I have then position this camera in a particular stationary setup and put a plate with 8 marker points in front of the camera. I have calculated the camera pose with respect to the coordinate system of those markers using the formula:
cameraPosition = -np.matrix(rotM).T * np.matrix(tvec),
where rotM is the rotational matrix and tvec is the translation vector obtained with opencv's cv.solvePnP
I wanted to check, how accurate the calculated camera pose is, but have stumbled into a problem, which is, that I do not know, to what physical point does the cameraPosition vector points to.
I firstly thought that it points to the center of the image plane, but now I've read that it points to the center of projection point.
Which is it? And if it's indeed the center of projection, how could I calculate, where that is located in my camera (using a certain camera settings)?
Thanks

use 4x4 matrices instead or rvec/tvec. never ever apply a transform in pieces (rvec, tvec). it's way too much of a headache to think about.

-np.matrix(rotM).T * np.matrix(tvec) is the reverse operation from converting a point (xw yw zw) in the world coordinates into camera coordinates, when that point is (0,0,0) in camera system.
[R R R tx][xw]
[R R R ty][yw]
[R R R tz][zw]
[0 0 0 1 ][1 ]

is Xc = rotM@Xw + tvec (Xw=[xw,yw,zw], tvec=[tx,ty,tz], rotM=R)
So reverse operation is  Xw = RotM⁻¹@(Xc-tvec) aka Xw = RotM.T@(Xc-tvec), since, for a rotation matrix, inverse and transpose are the same.
If Xc=[0,0,0], that is Xw=-rotM.T@tvec
So, indeed, that points to the center of projection (origin of camera coordinates system), expressed in the world coordinates. It tells you where the camera is in your world coordinates (the one you used to position physical points in the 3D world)
To end up in the center of the image, that takes a projection (canonical projection matrix, times intrisinc matrix), that would lead to [cx,cy], the position of the camera direction in the image (usually the middle of the image, but not necessarily). But the only point in the world that you cannot project happens to be the center of the projection. So to get that, you need first to add something (anything) to Zc
So, I do not know how to you intend to use that "center of projection expressed in world coordinates" to check your projection. Maybe to verify that, in your world coordinates, that point indeed to where the physical camera is? (in reality, not exactly: that is the center of projection. It is a virtual point created by lens. But, well, it should be not far from a point "inside" the camera, at a focal distance from the lens.

Thank you for answering. So my intention is to check, how accurately can I calculate the camera pose. I know with precision of about 1mm, what is the centre of image plane in world coordinates (due to rigidity of my setup and camera schematics) and am wondering how can I calculate the center of projection (in world coordinates), knowing the camera's characteristics:
Camera:
https://docs.baslerweb.com/aca2440-75um
Lens:
https://www.rmaelectronics.com/vs-technology-sv-1614hf/

Plane (the ccd sensor, theoretically) should be at [0,0,f] in camera coordinates. So RotM.T@([0,0,f]-tvec). I don't know how this really apply in real world (how theory really works in practice) and if you can really find, with that 1mm accuracy that position (besides, on camera I own, it is not easy to locale that. Even on a smartphone camera (so very flat), I am not really sure, at 1mm precision, where is the plane). But, well, theoretically it is at [0,0,f] in camera coordinates, so RotM.T@([0,0,f]-tvec) in world coordinates.

Thank you! Is that the case for every camera or just a pinhole camera?
I achieve about 1 mm accuracy due to rigid setup and measurements done with a precise laser ray as well as knowing the camera's schematics as it is provided by the manufacturer and matches the real cameras quite well.

I am not really versed in those things, so not sure. Afaik, no camera (if you exclude literal "chambers = camera" of the XIXth century ; or maybe some huge neutronic camera in orbit, and even those use some mask, such as MURA to act as a lens) are really literally pinhole cameras. And all cameras I've never use are modeled as pinhole camera. Because the whole point of the lens is to make "as if" there was a pinhole (the hole is bigger than a pin, so that lot a photons can pass through; but the lens make them all follow a direction "as if" they were all passing through a pinhole, that is

that a photon emitted from a given point has to reach the screen from a constant given direction.

So, not sure what you have in mind by "non-pinhole camera", since (afaik) they all are (in a sense) or none (in another sense).

But, well, all my reasoning was based on pinhole model.  Note that I haven't covered the fact that, since that center of projection is "virtual" (the center of projection is the 'virtual pinhole", the point all the rays seems to be passing through, "as if" there were a pinhole), its location depends on the lenses. So it could be before of behind the plane (the ccd sensor — with actual pinhole, it would have to be before: if an actual pinhole was behind the plane, then it would be void).

Usually, it is behind.  Hence the [0,0,f] coordinates of the center of the plane in camera coordinates. But if it is before, for example for an actual pinhole camera (with the image inverted upside-down on the plane, but of course, you wouldn't know, since it would be reversed by the electronic/software)  then coordinates of the plane is [0,0,-f] (assuming f is positive). If you have 1mm accuracy, with a typical f in the order of magnitudes of in cm, that would be very easy to discriminate.

Another possible meaning of "non-pinhole camera" would be to designate fisheye cameras. There again, afaik, all cameras are fisheyes camera. For some it shows more than for others. There, you need to correct for distortion before reasonning. And that may be easier said than done, since you need to revert it. But fortunately, you are interested in the center of the plane, and that center is, usually (even when it is not in the middle of the image) the only point that is not impacted by fisheye distorsion.

So, I can't be certain for 100% of the cameras. There might be specific cases I am not aware of. Besides, I am no camera expert. But I would bet that, unless you have a very very specific camera (and I guess you would have told us about that specificity), the general rule "plane is at [0,0,f]" (or maybe [0,0,-f]) applies

Thank you for a very thorough comment. I have a rather normal camera, as I linked in my first comment to your answer. I was only wondering if it would be possible that the distance between the sensor and the center of projection would be smaller (or larger) than f. Or to put it differently, why are those always by a focal distant apart?

Well, that is the definition of "focal distance": it is the distance between center of projection and plane (hence the fact that it could be also -f, rather than +f, depending on if the center of projection is before or behind the plane. But distance has to be f, or else f is not really the focal distance. Now, how that theory can really be measured in physical world, I don't know. I've never tried. I am interested to know tho: it is always satisfying to discover that abstract theory happens to be true

I had to tweak my setup a bit, so I will carry out the measurements next week and will let you know, how close are the measured and calculated camera positions :)
